# Why are these Capybara matchers having a different outcome? Shouldn't they be equivalent here?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I have been trying to figure out why me matchers aren't matching, and that's lead me to the following two tests:

```
subject.has_field?("filter").should be_true
subject.has_xpath?(".//input[contains(@id, 'filter')]").should be_true
```

The second of these tests results in a success, but the first fails. But the definition of has_field seems to indicate that in any situation where the second passes, the first should pass as well. What am I missing here?

Here's the HTML element:

```
<input id="filter_1" type="checkbox" name="type[ids][]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: `has_field?` should match only "typable" fields (and checkboxes) - it filters out inputs with `type=image`, `type=submit` and `type=hidden`. Could this be a reason for your problem?

Also, `has_field?` check for equivalence, at least in regards to ids, so it wouldn't match something with trailing characters in the id.

Comment: Good try at least - while it didn't solve my problem, I hadn't realized it filtered out certain types, so this might help another issue I've been having. I've also included the html in the question in case something else in it might be relevant. +1, though.

Comment: @GlyphGryph, `<input id="filter_1"`? Shouldn't `has_field?` check for equivalence?